# Load CSV files with Apache Spark - Java API

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark

I am new to Spark and working my way through the Java and Scala API and I was interested to put together two examples with a view of comparing both languages in terms of conciseness and readability.

Here is my Scala version:

```
import java.io.StringReader
import au.com.bytecode.opencsv.CSVReader
import org.apache.spark.{SparkConf, SparkContext}

object LoadCSVScalaExample {
  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("MyLoadCSVScalaExampleApplication").setMaster("local[*]")
    val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
    val input = sc.textFile("D:\\MOCK_DATA_spark.csv")
    val result = input.map { line => val reader = new CSVReader(new StringReader(line));
      reader.readNext()
    }
    print("This is the total count " + result.count())
  }
}
```

Whereas this is the Java counterpart:

```
import au.com.bytecode.opencsv.CSVReader;
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf;
import org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaRDD;
import org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext;
import org.apache.spark.api.java.function.Function;

import java.io.StringReader;

public class LoadCSVJavaExample implements Function<String, String[]> {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SparkConf conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("MyLoadCSVJavaExampleApp").setMaster("local[*]");
        JavaSparkContext sc = new JavaSparkContext(conf);
        JavaRDD<String> csvFile = sc.textFile("D:\\MOCK_DATA_spark.csv");
        JavaRDD<String[]> csvData = csvFile.map(new LoadCSVJavaExample());
        System.out.println("This prints the total count " + csvData.count());
    }

    public String[] call(String line) throws Exception {
        CSVReader reader = new CSVReader(new StringReader(line));
        return reader.readNext();
    }
}
```

I am not sure, however, whether the Java example is actually correct? Can I pick your brain on it? I know I could use the [Databrickd Spark csv library](https://github.com/databricks/spark-csv), instead, but I was wondering whether the current example is correct and how it can be further improved upon.

Thank you for your help,

I.

Comment: They look identical to me. Do they yield unexpected results?

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov, thanks for your comment, appreciated. No, I am not returned with any unexpected results, but I was wondering whether I can improve it in any way (the Java version). Any suggestion? At the moment, I am printing out the total row count.